# make div content move animation in a div wrapper and hide when it move out div wrapper

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want when div 'content'  goes to max size (go out div 'wrap') of div 'wrap' by animation.css{left: 900px}, div 'content'  also would not be seen with style like animation on. I using `z-index` CSS too but it can't run with my wish.
here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
            <div id="content" >these some text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content
{

position:absolute;
background-color:red;
float:left

}
#wrap{
   position:relative;
   width: 900px;
   float: left;
   height: 22px;
   margin:auto;
   border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function ()
 {
        var div = $("#content");
    setInterval(function () {
        div.css({ left: '0px' });
       div.animate({ left: 900px }, { duration: 4200 });
            
        }, 5500);
        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `animate()` function you used `left: 900px`. Since 900px is a string it needs to have quotes around it. Or, alternatively, you can just put `900`.. jQuery will add 'px' by default.

Other than that, it seems to work, as seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/YFBG5/